# How implement RxJs using jQuery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rxjs

This is my implementation:

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise( $.ajax({
        url     : url + postal_value +  '&types=(regions)&location=51.509865,-0.118092&key=' + key,
        type    : "GET",
        datatype: "json"
    }));
```

but the ajax call proceeds even without subscribe.
Is that right?

Comment: If you ran that `$.ajax()` line by itself, the AJAX call would take place. Surrounding it with a call to Rx.Observable.fromPromise() doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call is a promise which will start executing as soon as you call it. You need to defer execution by wrapping it in `Rx.Observable.defer(() => Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.ajax(/*...*/)))` so it only gets wired when actually subscribing to it

Comment: I'm using rxjs-jquery, but still $.ajaxAsObservable fires even without subscribe.

Comment: ajaxAsObservable doesnt make $.ajax lazy (see https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rxjs-jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js). Wrap it with `Rx.Observable.defer()` to make it lazy